# Looping through a range of rows using a string

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that will enter ranges within a chart's data labels via the "Label Contains: Value From Cells" option. Each label corresponds to a row within a sheet such as `=Breakdown!$B$27:$K$27`. I recorded a macro to find the language for this action and it came back as:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange. _
    InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, "=Breakdown!$B$27:$K$27", 0
```

I can loop through the SeriesCollection by "Dim i As Integer". Is there any way I can set `=Breakdown!$B$27:$K$27` as a string or something with variables for the cell numbers so that I can cycle through the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using string concatenate operator `&` and CStr function which converts an expression into a string, it'll work out well.

`"=Breakdown!$B$" & CStr(i) & ":$K$" & CStr(i)`